# Basic Probability of 3 Events with 1 event being disjoint from the other 2.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, inclusion-exclusion

Given that $\textrm{P}(Cc) = 0.82, \textrm{P}(B \cup C) = 0.41, \textrm{P}(A \cup C) = 0.52, \textrm{P}(A \cup B \cup C) = 0.69$. The event $C$ is disjoint from events $A$ and $B$. Compute

a.) $\textrm{P}(Ac ∪ Bc ∪ C)$

b. $\textrm{P}(Ac ∩B ∩ Cc).$

Here is what I have worked out:

a.)

$\textrm{P}(C) = 1 - \textrm{P}(Cc)$

$\textrm{P}(C) = 1 - 0.82$

$\textrm{P}(C) = 0.18$

$\textrm{P}(A ∪ C) = 0.52$

$\textrm{P}(A) + \textrm{P}(C) - 0 = 0.52$

$\textrm{P}(A) = 0.52 - 0.18$

$\textrm{P}(A) = 0.34, \textrm{P}(Ac) = 0.66$

$\textrm{P}(B ∪ C) = 0.41$

$\textrm{P}(B) + \textrm{P}(C) - 0 = 0.41$

$\textrm{P}(B) = 0.41 - 0.18$

$\textrm{P}(B) = 0.23, \textrm{P}(Bc) = 0.77$

$\textrm{P}(Ac ∪ Bc ∪ C) = \textrm{P}(Ac) + \textrm{P}(Bc) + \textrm{P}(C) - \textrm{P}(A ∪ C) - \textrm{P}(B ∪ C)$

$\textrm{P}(Ac ∪ Bc ∪ C) = 0.66 + 0.77 + 0.18 - 0.52 - 0.41$

$\textrm{P}(Ac ∪ Bc ∪ C) = 0.68$

b.

$\textrm{P} (Ac ∩B ∩ Cc) = 0$

Since $C$ is disjoint from $A$ and $B$, they have no intersections.

I am having a hard time trying to visualize how to calculate such a problem. Is my line of thought correct and if not, could it be explained where I went wrong. (if possible with a venn diagram on top of the calculation?)

Comment: You started strong with $\Pr(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)=\Pr(A^c)+\dots$ but somehow you continued that incorrectly.  It should have been $=\Pr(A^c)+\Pr(B^c)+\Pr(C)-\Pr(A^c\cap B^c)-\Pr(A^c\cap C)-\Pr(B^c\cap C)+\Pr(A^c\cap B^c\cap C)$ if you wanted to approach by inclusion-exclusion here.

Comment: There is a far easier approach however.  If you look at your venn diagram, you can see that $\Pr(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)$ is going to be the entire sample space with the exception of $A\cap B$, if you are able to figure out what that will be.

Comment: @JMoravitz Just to clarify, anytime I come across any intersection with C, it'd equal 0 when simplifying since it is disjoint from A and B? 

eg: Pr(Ac∩C) = 0, Pr(Bc∩C) = 0, Pr(Ac∩Bc∩C) = 0

Comment: $A^c\cap C = C$ since it was $A$ and $C$ who are disjoint, implying that $A^c$ is a superset of $C$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $\Pr(A\cup B\cup C)=0.69$, from $\Pr(C)=1-\Pr(C^c)=1-0.82=0.18$, and from $C$ is disjoint from $A$ and from $B$ (*and thus disjoint from $A\cup B$*) we get:

$$\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A\cup B\cup C)-\Pr(C)=0.68-0.18=0.5$$

We similarly find $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A\cup C)-\Pr(C)=0.52-0.18=0.34$ and $\Pr(B)=\Pr(B\cup C)-\Pr(C)=0.41-0.18=0.23$

By a rearrangement of inclusion-exclusion, $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cup B)=0.34+0.23-0.5=0.07$

We get finally then looking at the venn diagram or by standard results $\Pr(A^c\cup B^c\cup C)=\Pr(A^c\cup B^c) = 1-\Pr(A\cap B)=0.93$

Your answer for part (b) was correct.